# How to convert java.time.ZonedDateTime to XMLGregorianCalendar?

Tags: java, datetime, jax-ws, java-8, java-time

Is there any short way to convert java.time.ZonedDateTime to XMLGregorianCalendar?

Maybe I need some intermediate steps like convert ZonedDateTime to java.util.Date, but that will make code too messy.

The problem appeared in JAX-WS web services, datetime there is passed as XMLGregorianCalendar.

Comment: Show some code how you are doing it. I had that issue but to convert from XMLGregorianCalendar to a normal date without the timezone just simple `yyyy-MM-dd` date. Due to the fact that Java JAX-WS maps dates to XMLGregorianCalendar instead of Date even if you defined that as such in your WSDL data types.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

At the current moment I think it's the most straightforward way to do it:

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = GregorianCalendar.from(now); 
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGregorianCalendar = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(gregorianCalendar);
```

Comment: To other readers: Be aware of the time zone involved here. When the optional `ZoneId` argument is omitted from `ZonedDateTime.now`, the JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly assigned. I recommend instead always specifying explicitly your desired/expected time zone. Example: `ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )`. The rest of the Answer here is spot-on correct.